# Cannot Access Resource from Another Class

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to read storage_list.xml file. When I run the code below in my MainActivity's onCreate method, it works fine. But when I run it from method of another class it just doesn't work (they are in the same package). Why does this happen and what can i do?

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("storage_list", "xml", "android");
XmlResourceParser xrp = context.getResources().getXml(id);
```

It gives this exception:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/xml/storage_list.xml from xml type xml resource ID #0x10f000c

**Note:** context is the current instance of MainActivity which created the second class. I passed it from the constructor. I replace it with this when testing for MainActivity

**Edit:** I think the code above fails because I use the context for different things before I get the resource. But I don't know the exact reason, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Change the context object from being instance of mainactivity to be instance of Context that you intialize in your mainactivity

Comment: It already is like that. Sorry for ambiguity, I fixed it now.

Comment: Never mind, I wish I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. With the context mentioned above, I was getting AssetManager and calling its close method. When I removed assetManager.close() it's fixed.